# Location manager requestAlwaysAuthorization permission alert

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios8, cllocationmanager

I am using  `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`  when user open the app then there is a permission alert coming  "Allow click to access your location even when you are not using the app"

as well as if I am  using

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

I want to get the answer of the user (allow or disallow) there is an event that indicate of user selection?

Answer (score 0):

after ask, you can call authorizationStatus, here an example:

```
    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
        NSLog(@"User said yes");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```